# Change Vuex state right after hydration?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, server-side-rendering

My Vue application uses server-side rendering. When the app has loaded and hydrated, I'd like to detect a condition on the client and then commit a mutation.

If I touch the state before mounting the app, this warning is printed - as expected:

> [Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching
>   server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML
>   markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside `<p>`, or
>   missing `<tbody>`. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side
>   render.

I thought I'd find a **hook that would be called right after the hydration is done**.

I tried committing the mutation in the `mounted` hook of the main component. I also tried doing it after `app.$mount(...)`, and with `Vue.nextTick()`. All of these were too early: in each of these cases, I get the above warning.

I found two workarounds:

1. adding a `mounted` hook in the child component that will render differently with the modified state. That hook is called *after* the parent hook. Okay for now, since I only need to use it one place. But will get dirty when I need it in two different components.
2. using an obscure `setTimeout()`. Breaks easily, since I found no easy way to check whether the hydration is complete, so I can't poll. (The `data-server-rendered` attribute is removed when hydration begins.)

Any ideas how this could be solved properly?

Comment: What about using a watcher on a getter so you know when the state is hydrated? See `watch` here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/api.html